# mysql replication does not connect

Tags: mysql, replication

Using os is window. I made to mysql server 8.0 folder so one can be master(MySQL Server8.0) and other can be slave(MySQL Server 8.0_slave). I modified two edit files, and each server works well, and I made user rep with password.

But the connection doesn't work. as i star slave and show slave status, it goes

```
mysql> show slave status \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Connecting to source
                  Master_Host: 127.0.0.1
                  Master_User: rep
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: binary-bin.000001
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 883
               Relay_Log_File: [computer name]-relay-bin.000001
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4
        Relay_Master_Log_File: binary-bin.000001
             Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
```

Slave_IO_State keeps connect. As I checked .err here's  message like this

```
[ERROR] [MY-010584] [Repl] Slave I/O for channel '': error connecting to master 'rep@127.0.0.1:3306' - retry-time: 60 retries: 13 message: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' reported error: Authentication requires secure connection. Error_code: MY-002061
```

so I tried `change master to get_master_public_key=1;` command in slave mysql, and it goes

```
mysql> show slave status \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: 
                  Master_Host: 127.0.0.1
                  Master_User: rep
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: binary-bin.000001
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 883
               Relay_Log_File: [computer name]-relay-bin.000001
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4
        Relay_Master_Log_File: binary-bin.000001
             Slave_IO_Running: No
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
```

```
[ERROR] [MY-013117] [Repl] Slave I/O for channel '': Fatal error: The slave I/O thread stops because master and slave have equal MySQL server ids; these ids must be different for replication to work (or the --replicate-same-server-id option must be used on slave but this does not always make sense; please check the manual before using it). Error_code: MY-013117
```

(my master server id is 1 and slave server id is 2.) I can't figure how i can fix this.

Comment: Please ask database administrator related questions on their dedicated DBA sister site of SO. SO is for software development related questions only.

Comment: you mean i asked at wrong site?

Comment: Yes, you asked this question at the wrong site. You should delete the question from here and ask it on the DBA site.

Comment: [Creating a User for Replication - Important](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-howto-repuser.html#:~:text=of%20user%20accounts.-,Important,-To%20connect%20to)

Comment: "my master server id is 1 and slave server id is 2" -- the error message says otherwise.